# How to combine date time and Timezone offset in an ASP.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone

My web service call to a third party applications returns the date,time zone and timezone_offset values. I need to add this to a calendar in Asp.net application. What is the best way to combine this together so that my date object understands that its from Eastern time zone?

```
<start_date>2014-11-17 19:00:00</start_date>
<timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
<timezone_offset>GMT-0500</timezone_offset>
```

Comment: Try NodaTime for this - http://nodatime.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the offset too, you can use DateTimeOffset.Parse() to get the DateTimeOffset. From there, you can read the DateTime property. The output dt variable will have 2014-11-17 7:00:00 PM with DateTimeKind property set to "Unspecified"

```
var dtOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2014-11-17 19:00:00-0500", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var dt = dtOffset.DateTime;
```

A DateTimeOffset represents a point in time. Usually, its relative to UTC. So, it is a natural structure to initially parse the fields that you have.

If you want a reference to the same datetime in UTC, you can use this. Here the output dt variable will have 2014-11-18 12:00:00 AM with DateTimeKind property set to "Utc"

```
 var dt = DateTime.Parse("2014-11-17 19:00:00-0500", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime();
```

If you don't have the offset but just have the timeZoneId, you can still do it but you need NodaTime for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll focus on this part of the question:

> What is the best way to combine this together so that my date object understands that its from Eastern time zone?

There is no data type built in to .NET that can sufficiently do that.  The `DateTimeOffset` type associates with a particular offset, such as the `-05:00` or `-04:00` that might be in use by the Eastern time zone (depending on the date).  But those same offsets might also be sourced from some other time zone entirely.  A time zone *has* one or more offsets, but an offset isn't a time zone itself.

Fortunately there are solutions.  There are two options to consider:

1. You could pair a `DateTimeOffset` with a `TimeZoneInfo` object.  When storing or transmitting these,  you would only send the full `DateTimeOffset` along with the `Id` of the time zone.
2. The [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library is a much more effective way to work with date and time, especially when it comes to time zone concerns.  It contains a type called [`ZonedDateTime`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_ZonedDateTime.htm) that already combines a date, time, offset, and time zone.  It can also be used to work with IANA time zone identifiers, such as the `"America/New_York"` time zone you specified in the question.